# Alternative to symlink in C++ Builder

Tags: c, c++builder, symlink

I'm currently trying to integrate a C code written for UNIX in C++ Builder. But a part of the code is using the function symlink :

```
if(!fname
|| (use_real_copy ? real_copy(path, fname) : symlink(path, fname))
```

I don't know how to replace it so it works in C++ Builder for Windows 64 bits, I've found the functions CreateSymbolicLinkW and CreateSymbolicLinkA that seem to be the equivalent for Windows but C++ Builder can't find them.

Do you have any idea of how I can get around this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried with CreateSymbolicLink (note the lack of A or W)? The A/W are the ansi/wide versions of the functions in the API, but you usually call the one without anything, so the compiler chooses which one to call depending on the project.

Comment: What do you mean by _can't find them_? Is it the compiler or the linker? Actually what's the error message?

Comment: Thank you for this information. Yes I've tried with CreateSymbolicLink, but it's the same problem, that it's an "implicit declaration [...]". I've tried to include "windows.h" but it raised an error in this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`CreateSymbolicLink()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363866.aspx) is declared in `winbase.h`, which is `#include`'d by `windows.h`, which is `#include`'d by `vcl.h` in all VCL-based projects.  If you are not creating a VCL project, make sure you have an `#include <windows.h>` statement in your code.  Either way, also make sure that `_WIN32_WINNT` is defined to be at least `0x0600` (Vista+).

If the compiler still complains that `CreateSymbolicLink()` is undefined then you must be using an old version of C++Builder (`CreateSymbolicLink()` was added to C++Builder's copy of `winbase.h` in C++Builder 2007), in which case you will have to declare `CreateSymbolicLink()` manually in your own code, eg:

```
#define SYMBOLIC_LINK_FLAG_DIRECTORY            (0x1)

#define VALID_SYMBOLIC_LINK_FLAGS  SYMBOLIC_LINK_FLAG_DIRECTORY // & whatever other flags we think of!

WINBASEAPI
BOOLEAN
APIENTRY
CreateSymbolicLinkA (
    __in LPCSTR lpSymlinkFileName,
    __in LPCSTR lpTargetFileName,
    __in DWORD dwFlags
    );
WINBASEAPI
BOOLEAN
APIENTRY
CreateSymbolicLinkW (
    __in LPCWSTR lpSymlinkFileName,
    __in LPCWSTR lpTargetFileName,
    __in DWORD dwFlags
    );
#ifdef UNICODE
#define CreateSymbolicLink  CreateSymbolicLinkW
#else
#define CreateSymbolicLink  CreateSymbolicLinkA
#endif // !UNICODE
```

But then you have another problem to tackle - that version of C++Builder would also not have the `CreateSymbolicLinkA` and `CreateSymbolicLinkW` symbols in its copy of `kernel32.lib` for linking to the exported functions in `kernel32.dll`.  So you would have to create a new `.lib` import library from a modern `kernel32.dll` that includes those symbols, and then add it to your project.  At which point, it would probably be easier to just dynamically load `CreateSymbolicLink()` at runtime using `GetProcAddress()` instead:

```
typedef BOOLEAN (APIENTRY *LPFN_CSL)(LPCTSTR, LPCTSTR, DWORD);

LPFN_CSL lpCreateSymbolicLink = (LPFN_CSL) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32")),
    #ifdef UNICODE
    "CreateSymbolicLinkW"
    #else
    "CreateSymbolicLinkA"
    #endif
);
if (lpCreateSymbolicLink)
{
    // use lpCreateSymbolicLink(...) as needed...
}
```

Which will also allow your code to run on XP and earlier (if needed), since `CreateSymbolicLink()` was added in Vista.

Comment: Including <windows.h> in my C file is actually raising an error, "unknown 'OUT' type name" in rpcdcep.h, I don't know why. I'm using <windows.h> in the same project though, but in a C++ file.